# authWithOAuthPopup Error on Web Platform

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am trying to use Firebase's Facebook authentication on a webpage, but I get this error:

```
Login failed Error: Invalid authentication credentials provided.
at Error (native)
at http://45.55.203.213/js/firebase.js:160:367
at e (http://45.55.203.213/js/firebase.js:140:400)
```

Here's my Javascript code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://fantasy-smash-bros.firebaseio.com/");

function FBLogin() {
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login failed", error);
        } else {
            loginWithAuthData(authData);
        }
    });
}

function loginWithAuthData(authData) {
    username = authData.facebook.displayName;
    avatarURL = authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url;
    userID = authData.facebook.id;
}

function attemptLogin() {
    var user = ref.getAuth();
    if (user) {
        loginWithAuthData(user);
    } else {
        $("#fb-login").click(function () {
            FBLogin();
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    attemptLogin();
});
```

Note: I have imported firebase.js. [Here's](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js) a copy of the Javascript I used.

I believe I have setup everything correctly: adding Firebase's callback URL to my Facebook app's whitelist, enabling Facebook authentication on the Firebase app. But I am still stumped on what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured any app restrictions with Facebook? Such as a different domain that auth.firebase.com, or private-only / sandbox access, or restricting access to certain IPs?

Comment: Yes, I configured the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in the Facebook app. Is that enough, or do I have to add additional URIs?

Comment: Does the popup come up at all or when do you get the error?

Comment: Per [Javascript Guide > User Authentication > Handling Errors](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-handling-errors), Firebase logs an error with a `code`, `message`, and `details` fields. Can you log those value and post them here?

Comment: I found the problem: I forgot to add my domain to "Authorized Domains for OAuth Redirects" in the Firebase dashboard. I also added my domain to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" in the Facebook app dashboard, thought I don't know if that made a difference. Thanks for your help!